# Get the list of all the device connected in same network

Tags: android, sockets, network-programming, android-networking

How can I get the List of all the device connected in same WiFi network. I did find couple of applications are working perfectly available on Google Play like "Who is on My WiFi" and "WiFi Inspector". I want to implement the same functionality in my application.

Answer (score 0):

I find out this code to show all the connected Ips to the same WI-FI:

```
private int LoopCurrentIP = 0;
String ad ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //ArrayList<InetAddress> ar = getConnectedDevices( );

}



public ArrayList<InetAddress> getConnectedDevices(String YourPhoneIPAddress) {
    ArrayList<InetAddress> ret = new ArrayList<InetAddress>();

    LoopCurrentIP = 0;

    String IPAddress = "";
    String[] myIPArray = YourPhoneIPAddress.split("\\.");
    InetAddress currentPingAddr;


    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
        try {

            // build the next IP address
            currentPingAddr = InetAddress.getByName(myIPArray[0] + "." +
                    myIPArray[1] + "." +
                    myIPArray[2] + "." +
                    Integer.toString(LoopCurrentIP));
            ad = currentPingAddr.toString();   /////////////////
            Log.d("MyApp",ad);                 //////////////

            // 50ms Timeout for the "ping"
            if (currentPingAddr.isReachable(50)) {

                ret.add(currentPingAddr);
                ad = currentPingAddr.toString();        /////////////////
                Log.d("MyApp",ad);                     //////////////
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }

        LoopCurrentIP++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```